# iptable_nat stopped working after update

Tags: iptables, fedora-28

Today, I installed some updates with `dnf update`.
After that I cant set some basic iptables rules.

```
$ iptables -A INPUT --match state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT`
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

This command runnig forever

```
$ modprobe iptable_nat
```

and also this run forever

```
$ iptables -t nat -L
```

Other rules working nice.
Has anybody a tip to solve this issue?

Info of dnf-update

```
Transaction performed with:
    Installed     dnf-2.7.5-2.fc27.noarch  @updates
    Installed     rpm-4.14.2-1.fc27.x86_64 @updates
Packages Altered:
    Erase    kernel-4.18.13-100.fc27.x86_64         @updates
    Install  kernel-4.18.16-100.fc27.x86_64         @updates
    Erase    kernel-core-4.18.13-100.fc27.x86_64    @updates
    Install  kernel-core-4.18.16-100.fc27.x86_64    @updates
    Erase    kernel-devel-4.18.12-100.fc27.x86_64   @updates
    Install  kernel-devel-4.18.16-100.fc27.x86_64   @updates
    Upgraded kernel-headers-4.18.15-100.fc27.x86_64 @updates
    Upgrade                 4.18.16-100.fc27.x86_64 @updates
    Erase    kernel-modules-4.18.13-100.fc27.x86_64 @updates
    Install  kernel-modules-4.18.16-100.fc27.x86_64 @updates
    Upgraded vim-minimal-2:8.1.450-1.fc27.x86_64    @updates
    Upgrade              2:8.1.483-1.fc27.x86_64    @updates
Scriptlet output:
   1 warning: file /lib/modules/4.18.13-100.fc27.x86_64/updates: remove failed: No such file or directory
   2 cat: write error: Broken pipe
   3 Running as unit: run-ra5568fc978d4459eb86c989526d8c755.service
   4 Running as unit: run-rfcb91a7b68a94775bb87bf88d9608331.service
```

Comment: First rule the ACCEPT has an apostrophe after the T.  Also you could try **-j ACCEPT**  Also you could try this **iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT**

Comment: Same error like `iptables -A INPUT --match state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT`

Comment: what version of iptables are you using?

Comment: `iptables v1.6.2`

Comment: iptables v.1.8.1 is current I would try updating first.

Comment: How can I update to 1.8.1? 1.6.2 is the newest in the repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85165/discussion-between-cybernard-and-user6537157).

Comment: Same issue with `iptables v1.8.0` and fedora 29.